# Open webpage in Google Chrome from Safari in iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, google-chrome, ios7

I found this code on the Internet:

```
javascript:location.href="googlechrome"+location.href.substring(4);
```

If that code is put in a bookmark in Safari, it will open the Chrome browser and load the current webpage the user had in Safari.

But what I want is when the user clicks on the bookmark, Chrome will open a website that I have set (e.g., www.google.com) instead of giving me the current tab of the Safari browser.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

```
javascript:location.href="googlechrome://gooogle.com"
```

or in the html:

```
<a href="googlechrome://gooogle.com">Go to link in googlechrome</a>
```

Comment: is there a way to do this on desktops? Like a link that says 'Open this website in Google Chrome' and it will open in Chrome. I already tried href="chrome://google.com" but this didn't work :(

Comment: How about the reverse? Is there a way to open Safari with a URL in Chrome?

Comment: @JustinPutney Did you ever get a solution for this? I'm looking to launch a vnc link, safari has the functionality built in whereas chrome requires a plugin, so if I can launch safari it will save me a heap of trouble.

Comment: @SeanT No. I haven't. I need the same thing. "Save to Home Screen" is only available in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Add `openwith.link/` to the beginning of any url in Safari to see a list of browsers to open the link in. For example: http://openwith.link/youtube.com will allow you to open YouTube in Chrome, Firefox or Coast (as long as you have them installed)

Comment: For full disclosure, I'm the creator of this site. I hope it helps. :)

Comment: This sounds awesome, but the site is down. Would you mind posting some code here about how this can be accomplished?