open website in external browser instead of in-app
I have gone through multiple SO question but there is no proper solution to the answer so I have tried chatgpt and some answers and created a script which is working fine and opening website in chrome instead of in-app browser but facing a issue which is when open in chrome colon : is removed from url.
Here is the script
  (function () {
    const userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

    // Detect if the current browser is an in-app browser (Instagram, Facebook, etc.)
    const isInAppBrowser = /FBAN|FBAV|Instagram|Line|Twitter|WhatsApp|Snapchat/i.test(userAgent);

    // Detect iOS
    const isIOS = /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(userAgent);

    if (isInAppBrowser) {
      const url = "https://www.example.com/"; // Replace with your website's URL

      // Prevent infinite redirect loop using sessionStorage
      const alreadyRedirected = sessionStorage.getItem("redirected");
      if (!alreadyRedirected) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("redirected", "true");

        if (isIOS) {
          // Try to open in Chrome using the googlechrome:// scheme
          const chromeURL = `googlechrome://${url}`;

          setTimeout(() => {
            window.location.href = chromeURL;

            // Fallback to Safari after 500ms if Chrome isn't installed or doesn't open
            setTimeout(() => {
              window.location.href = url; // Fallback to Safari
            }, 500);
          }, 500);
        } else {
          // Android behavior: Trigger intent for Chrome or default browser
          window.location.href = `intent://${url.replace('https://', '')}#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.android.chrome;end;`;

          // Fallback if intent fails
          setTimeout(() => {
            window.location.href = url;
          }, 500);
        }
      }
    }
  })();

So instead of opening https://www.example.com it is opening https//www.example.com

Which case are we talking about, iOS or Android - or both? If iOS, I would assume it is because you are prefxing it with googlechrome:// - and :// more than once, makes for an invalid URL. Not sure if URL-encoding the value might help.

And I would probably not assume, that all users will have Chrome installed on their devices.

@C3roe Right now I am focusing on iOS only

That is second part that user has chrome or not, initially my focus is only on the opening website in external browser and that is only in iOS

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18959391/1427878 suggests you simply need to remove the https:// part from the URL, before you append it to googlechrome://
